# Express router calls the wrong route

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

So, I have an API with with a few routes defined (I'm not going to list all of them) where one of them never gets called unless I change it's name.

this is how I define them in code:

```
// Each middleware/function is separated by commas ofcourse
app.route('.../a/b/:params')
.get(someMiddlewares, someFunctions); 

app.route('.../a/b/c')
.get(someOtherMiddlewares, someOtherFunctions);
```

I what I noticed is that, since the first route is defined as ".../a/b/:params" and the second as ".../a/b/c", the first one allways gets called instead.

I have looked through a lot of questions and I have yet to find an answer or anyone with a similar enough problem and would like to know what I can do to fix this instead of just renaming routes.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.../a/b/:params` means `.../a/b/.*` in terms of regex. As, `.../a/b/c` also  matches this pattern it is expected behaviour to call the first functions.

Just put the `.../a/b/c` on top of the `.../a/b/:params` route.

```
app.route('.../a/b/c')
.get(someOtherMiddlewares, someOtherFunctions);

app.route('.../a/b/:params')
.get(someMiddlewares, someFunctions);
```

So that `/a/b/c` is matched first.